# Open set U whose outer measure is less than A + epsilon

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be any given set with $m^*(A)<\infty$ (outer measure finite).

Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an open set $U$ such that $A\subseteq U$ and $m^*(U)\leq m^*(A)+\epsilon$.

How do we prove it rigorously? My lecture notes says the proof is immediate but I don't really get how to prove it.

Intuitively I understand it, take $U$ to be "smallest" such set and the inequality will intuitively hold.

Comment: Isn't this a straightforward consequence of the definition of outer measure? (it is a $\sup$, so it deals with epsilon stuff)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$m^*(A)=\inf \{\sum I_n:A\subset \cup I_n\}$

So for any given $\epsilon>0$ by definition of  *greatest lower bound* of a set we will get a sequence of open intervals such that $A\subset \cup I_n$ and $m^*(A)+\epsilon >\sum I_n$.

Take the open set $O= \cup I_n$  and result follows

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful