# Need explanation open set U whose outer measure is less than A + epsilon

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I read from: [Open set U whose outer measure is less than A + epsilon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539792/open-set-u-whose-outer-measure-is-less-than-a-epsilon)

> Let $A$ be any given set with $m^*(A)<\infty$ (outer measure finite).
>
> Then for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an open set $U$ such that
> $A\subseteq U$ and $m^*(U)\leq m^*(A)+\epsilon$.

Then the answer is:

> $m^*(A)=\inf \{\sum I_n:A\subset \cup I_n\}$

> So for any given $\epsilon>0$ by definition of  *greatest lower bound*
> of a set we will get a sequence of open intervals such that $A\subset
>  \cup I_n$ and $m^*(A)+\epsilon >\sum I_n$.
>
> Take the open set $O= \cup I_n$  and result follows

I don't understand with that answer because I'm new in measure theory, why for any given $\epsilon>0$ by definition of  *greatest lower bound*
of a set we will get a sequence of open intervals such that $A\subset
 \cup I_n$ and $m^*(A)+\epsilon >\sum I_n$?
Anyone can give explanation for that proof?